# White square is displayed in imageview instead of image from mipmap

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I have the following screen:

[image]

As you can see, image is not displayed in `ImageView`. Here's the image I try to add to this `ImageView`

logo.png:

[image]

Here's the layout of screen I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/sign_in_sign_up"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_iv"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sign_in_tv"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/enter_login_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="@string/enter_your_login"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo_iv" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/enter_login_tv"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/enter_password_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="@string/enter_your_login"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login_et" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/enter_password_tv"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password_et" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/forgot_password_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/forgot_your_password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sign_in_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_with_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/or_login_with"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/forgot_password_tv" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.21" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So, what can cause such an issue that image is not displayed. I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: in which `mipmap` folder are your image exist for example `mipmap-hdpi , mipmap-mdpi, etc`

Comment: The `mipmap` resource directory is intended for launcher icons only. Can you just move your `logo.png` to the `drawable` directories?

Comment: @BenP. thanks a lot, it helped. Maybe write it as answer?